# Changing picture box on mouseover, and resetting on mouseleave

Tags: c++, .net, winforms, image, visual-c++

I am developing a windows form program and having a hard time finding how to do this in C++. The MSDN has this page, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image, but the C++ documentation is lacking compared to the VB.

This is what I have so far. This method is supposed to avoid the common flickering issues but I am not sure where to go from there since I need it to go back to the original image after the mouse leaves.

```
void InitializeComponent(void)
    {   
this->btnExit->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
        this->btnExit->BackgroundImageLayout = System::Windows::Forms::ImageLayout::None;
        this->btnExit->Image = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^  >(resources->GetObject(L"btnExit.Image")));
        this->btnExit->Location = System::Drawing::Point(764, 4);
        this->btnExit->Name = L"btnExit";
        this->btnExit->Size = System::Drawing::Size(30, 20);
        this->btnExit->TabIndex = 3;
        this->btnExit->TabStop = false;
        this->btnExit->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &mainForm::btnExit_Click);
}

#pragma endregion
private: System::Void btnExit_OnMouseEnter(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            Image^ get ();
            void set (Image^ value);
         }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private: System::Void btnExit_MouseEnter(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         btnExit->Image = Image::FromFile("C:\\Users\\...\\image.png");
 }
```

Works, not sure if it is the proper way to do it.